# JPA method increases version field of searching entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring boot 2.7.0

And have the next entities in simple:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    private String name;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    Account account;

    private String message;
}
```

and jpa repositories:

```java
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
}


@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long> {
    Page<Event> findAllByAccount(Account account, Pageable pageable);
}
```

In short I call

```java
eventRepository.findAllByAccount(accountRepository.findById(1), PageRequest.of(1,10));
```

Problem is every call of last code increases the version field of `Account` by 1. So question is why? I don't call any update or save method.
And additionally the result of this behaviour is calling of method needs

```java
 @Transactional(readonly=false)
```

Otherwise if I write `readonly=true` that throws `cannot execute UPDATE in a read-only transaction`

---

**ADDED**:

full code of usage:

```java
@Transactional
public Page<Event> events(Long accountId, int page) {
    return eventRepository.findByAccount(findById(accountId), PageRequest.of(page, PAGE_SIZE));
}
```

```java
@GetMapping("/events")
public List<EventResponse> listEvents(@RequestParam(value = "max", defaultValue = "0") int page) {
    return eventService.events(1L, page).stream().map(EventResponse::of).toList();
}
```

Comment: It seems like you are updating the entities returned by `findAllByAccount`. What's the method loading the entities looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like hibernate is deriving lockMode type as either of `WRITE` or `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` or `PESSIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` based on isolation level of your database. As per [reference](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/LockMode.html) hibernate decides this pessimistic locking by its own based on database you use.

As per [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#locking-LockMode), if lockmode type is either of what I mentioned above, `Version` will get automatically incremented even if you haven't changed anything i.e. even if you haven't do any update or save.

Please check database isolation level & based on that you might get an idea about this.

**Edit**: as you explicitly setting lockmode as write so my answer validates that because of WRITE mode, your version got incremented automatically.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, locking was reason of it

Comment: Glad it worked for you, consider accepting answer if you think its correct.

Answer (score 1):

The problem should be related in the code which is using the result of the find.

If you're modifying entities under a transaction they're going to be modified at the end of the method, when Spring in this case is going to close the transaction. In this part when transaction ends, the JPA provider (for example hibernate) aligns the relative entity record into the database with the 'java entity object' by an update.

Comment: Thank you for response. I added other part of code usage. There are no any change of objects at transaction, only reading list from db and return to response. That's why I was surprised

Comment: Try to share the exception stacktrace, when you mark the transaction read only.  @Transactional(readonly=true), maybe there're actors/interceptors around that are working without you not knowing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. After trim all my code to the posted and debug I found my mistake:
In the begin I was retrieving Account in another method by `.lock(Long)` method instead of `.findById(Long)`

lock method is below:

```java
@Lock(LockModeType.WRITE)
@Query("from Account where id = :id")
public Optional<Account> lock(Long id);
```

Comment: i just saw your answer, please check my answer about details.